# Targeting an element with only one class value

Tags: css, css-selectors

If I have two elements like this

```
<div class="one two three"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
```

And I want to grab the div that has only the `"one"` classname.

I know I can do this like this:

```
div[class="one"]
```

because if I do `div.one` it applies to both,

is there any other way to get the element with just the specified classname?

edit - the goal being to shorten the selector character count

Comment: Is there a problem with doing it like that? Or was this purely theoretical

Comment: theoretical, the attribute selector is a bit lengthy and can appear to be improper if a reviewer isn't aware of it's purpose to grab a specific element that only has that classname, it doesn't seem to be a common concept in CSS

Comment: I think the best way is `div[class="one"]` undoubtedly.

Comment: Or perhaps an ID - if your focus is the CSS

Comment: @BenMansley if only life were so perfect ;)

Comment: Hah, we can dream :)

Comment: @SohrabHejazi thanks, I understand this, the question's intent was to find other ways to do this, that's probably why you got a downvote

Comment: "I know I can do this like this:" sounds like making it clear to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`[class=one]` is currently the shortest way to select just the single class in CSS. If you are concerned that this will appear odd to other developers, just make sure to include a comment alongside it.

---

If you know the other classes, you can use the [`:not` pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot):

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
div.one {
  background: purple;
}
div.one:not(.two):not(.three) {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="one two three"></div>
<div class="one"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, I'm looking for something less lengthy, but I still upped you because :not() is something I hadn't even considered.

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer - If you could invent a css selector for this purpose, what would it look like? You can use just `[class=one]` to slightly simplify. What can be better than that?

Comment: well how about something like `!.one` where `!` indicates the following rule applies with explicit inclusion, thanks for the `[class=one]`, that's actually quite helpful if the class doesn't happen to appear on other element types

Comment: @RenaissanceProgrammer - that would be quite cool :) I have altered my answer and am going out on a limb to say that there is no other way to do this in pure CSS.

Answer (score 3):

Based on a review of all **[CSS Selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#selectors)**, I think these are your best options:

- `div[class="one"]`: a `div` whose class attribute value is exactly equal to "one"
- `div[class$="one"]`: a `div` whose class attribute value *ends* exactly with the string "one"

Comment: thanks, but $ makes it even longer and has potential conflicts with other possible classnames

Comment: I think your best answer was already in your question. `div[class="one"]` is tailor made for your request. I used the $ selector based on the code you displayed. The second `div` ends in "one", so that matches while excluding the first `div`.